# file_put_content create file if not exist?

Tags: php

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://www.test.com);
$file = '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test.html';
file_put_contents($file,$html);
```

Does file_put_content create the file test.html when file doesn't exists?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

yes.

as per [php documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php):

> If filename does not exist, the file is created.

Comment: and the existing file is overwritten.

Comment: yes. OP has asked it is created or not if file not exists. @Junaid Atique

Comment: Thanks alot I've visited that site before. I think I overlooked that line.

Comment: But the directory must exist already - at least in my current setup.

Comment: And what about when it doesn't exist but it's not created? ```Warning
: file_put_contents(/var/www/_logs/.htaccess): failed to open stream: No such file or directory```

Comment: In my case, FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH was necessary.